# is ng-model allowed inside <td> element of a table?

Tags: angularjs

Is ng-model allowed inside  element of a table? Will angular automatically update the model if I change a particular column(i.e. view)?

Comment: how do you intend to change *"a particular column"*? table elements cannot be used for input, while `ng-model` effectively binds interactive content elements to a scope.

Comment: actually I am creating a inline editable table. For that I want to associate model to columns so that when user types in something to column(i.e. view) angular automatically update the model, but it is not happening. I am not using input element. I am directly making table cells editable. Any suggestion for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are making the table cells directly editable using the HTML `contenteditable` attribute, ng-model won't work automatically as by default it's only for form elements.

It is possible to make it work with `contenteditable` though. There is an working example of how to do it on the angular website at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Bingo... it worked. Though I need to make some more workarounds but finally it worked using NgModelController :)

Answer (score 2):

ng-model is allowed wherever typical form elements exist that can use the directive ([input, select and textarea](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel))

One thing I will say about ng-model that can make it a bit tricky is that you will want to bind ng-model to a property of an object rather than just a simple scope variable. I have run into several instances where I bind $scope.foo to ng-model and use it in an input control. Then, if you clear the input field, the binding is lost and it stops updating the variable. Use something like $scope.fooObj.modelProp where fooObj is an object and it will work fine.

Comment: I am creating an inline editable table so I can not use input element to table columns. I tried using $scope.fooObj.property as well in ng-model but it also didn't help. Any suggestion?